# How to access one website from different directories in Kohana

Tags: kohana

I have big issue of how to do this.

I have a virtual host and access my project via it. I know want to redirect it to more friendly and accessible form.

What I use:

```
 http://localhost/api/users
```

What I want:

```
 http://api.mywebsite.com/users
```

I cannot determine if I should somehow change routes in boostrap.php or make some changes in .htaccess file (tried Redirect and RewriteRule but failed miserably). I would really welcome any kind of help on this topic.

(I am semi-begginer in programming, thanks for understanding that)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the */system/config/url.php* to */application/config/url.php*
pu